# Blur effect does not work when with position value of 'sticky' and border-radius greater than 4px

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed size div that scrolls vertically to reveal more content - I want a bottom rectangle on this fixed size div to apply a blur effect to the text behind it.

The fixed size div is .page

```css
.page {
  position: relative;
  width: 8.5in;
  height: 11in;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #333;

  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Latin Modern";
  //margin-left: 10%;

  border: solid #666666 5px;
  border-radius: 10px; // THIS BELOW 5PX ALLOWS BLUR
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The blurred div is .footer

```css
.footer {
  content:"";

  position: sticky; // THIS SET TO SOMETHING OTHER THAN STICKY ALLOWS BLUR

  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;

  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  -o-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  -moz-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Full demo here:

https://codepen.io/mattwilson888/pen/poxagZm

There are two compromises which can make the blur work.

1. Do not use `position: sticky;` inside the .footer.
2. Reduce the `border-radius` in `.article` such that it is no greater than `4px`.

The first option is not an acceptable compromise - the second one is acceptable, but I'd like to know what is going on and not make it. Why do these seemingly arbitrary changes affect if blur works at all?